# elliptic curve $~y^2 = x^3 + 3x +8~ (mod~ 13)~$ - torsion groups

Tags: elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

> **Corollary $6.4.$** Let $E$ be an elliptic curve and let $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $m \neq 0$.
>
> $(b)$ If $m \neq 0$ in $K$, i.e., if either $\operatorname{char}(K) = 0$ or $p := \operatorname{char}(K) > 0$ and $p \nmid m$, then $E[m] = \mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z}$.
>
> (page $86$ of [Silverman, The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves, $2^{nd}$ Edition])

Let $E: y^2 = x^3 + 3x + 8$ over $\mathbb{Z}/13 \mathbb{Z}$. I just calculated the points on this curve. There are $\#E[3] \stackrel{?}{=} 2$ points of order $3$ and $\#E[9] \stackrel{?}{=} 6$ points of order $~9~$.

$(i)~~$ I expected $9$ points of order $3$, since $\#E[3] = \#\left(\mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3 \mathbb{Z}\right) = 9$. Why are there just $2$ points of order $3$?

$(ii) ~~$ I calculated $\#E(\mathbb{Z}/13 \mathbb{Z}) = 9$ (by bruteforce). As far as I understand the above **Corollary 6.4**, there should be some points of order $5$, since $p = 13 \nmid 5$. But the existence of such a point $P \in E[5]$ would imply the existence of some subgroup $\langle P \rangle \leq E(\mathbb{Z}/13 \mathbb{Z})$ with order $5$ as-well. This can't happen, since the order of a subgroup must divide the order of the upper group. Since $5 \nmid 9$, there can't be any points of order $5$.

What am I missing?

Comment: For (ii), that Corollary in Silverman is referring to the structure of the $m$-torsion points over $\overline{K}$.

Comment: How did you calculate those points?

Comment: Are you sure the $9$-torsion isn't cyclic?

Comment: The theorem you cite is only valid when $K$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: @BrandonCarter : thanks a lot, i see my mistake now

Comment: @k.stm : i wrote a small program to check all pairs of Z/13Z and ended up with 9 valid points (8 pairs and the basepoint), afterwards i checked the orders

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : At least for E(Z/13Z) i can use the generator $P := (2, 3) \in E(K)$. Is the 9-torsion cyclic? wouldn't that imply the existence of some $\tilde{P} \in E(\overline{K})$ with order 81 and $\tilde{P} \in E[9]$? i tought maybe there is some other $Q \in E(\overline{K})$ with order 9 such that $\langle P, Q \rangle = E(\overline{K})$?

Comment: Yes, there will be another point $Q$ of order $9$, defined over an extension of $\Bbb F_{13}$, which together with $P$ generate the $9$-torsion of $E$ over the algebraic closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a computer assisted answer that shows explicitly the corresponding field extensions of $\Bbb F_{13}$ that contain all $3$-torsion, respectively all $9$-torsion points. (A comment would not fit with all delivered information.)

Sometimes it is good to be able to verify and construct explicitly objects in the framework of a given elliptic curve.

Things are already clear from the comments, but sometimes computer brute force clears by example alternatively or complementarily. If explicit, structural computations using [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) are not wanted, **please ignore** this answer.

---

We initialize the curve $E$ over the field with $p=13$ elements, ask for its order, generator(s), and points.

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve( GF(13), [3, 8] )
sage: E
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 3*x + 8 over Finite Field of size 13
sage: E.order().factor()
3^2
sage: for P in E.points():
....:     print "Point %8s of order %s" % (P.xy() if P != E(0) else 'ZERO', P.order())
....: 
Point     ZERO of order 1
Point   (1, 5) of order 9
Point   (1, 8) of order 9
Point   (2, 3) of order 9
Point  (2, 10) of order 9
Point   (9, 6) of order 3
Point   (9, 7) of order 3
Point  (12, 2) of order 9
Point (12, 11) of order 9
sage: E.gens()
((12 : 11 : 1),)
sage: G = E.gens()[0]    # the generator
sage: G.order()
9
```

We have all nine $\Bbb F_{13}$-rational points on $E$, a generator is the point $G= (-1,11)$ above.

---

Let us compute a suitable field extension of $\Bbb F_{13}$ that contains all $\bar{\Bbb F}_{13}$-three-torsion points. Sage computes for us the corresponding division polinomial (for the $x$-coordinate of a point $(x,y)$ on $E$). This polynomial is:

```
sage: E.division_polynomial(3).factor()
(3) * (x + 4) * (x^3 + 9*x^2 + 9*x + 9)
```

One root, $-4$, of this polynomial already lives over $\Bbb F_{13}$, it is the common $x$-component of the two points of order three listed above, $(9,\pm6)$. To have them all, the needed extension is...

```
sage: F.<a> = GF( 13^3, modulus = x^3 + 9*x^2 + 9*x + 9 )
sage: F
Finite Field in a of size 13^3
sage: F.modulus()
x^3 + 9*x^2 + 9*x + 9
sage: a.minpoly()
x^3 + 9*x^2 + 9*x + 9
sage: # we consider the base change of E from GF(13) to F = GF(13^3)
sage: EF = E.base_extend(F)
sage: EF
Elliptic Curve defined by y^2 = x^3 + 3*x + 8 over Finite Field in a of size 13^3
sage: EF.base_field()
Finite Field in a of size 13^3
sage: EF.base_field() == F
True
```

We let now sage compute the number of $F$-rational points, $F=\Bbb F_{13}(a)\cong \Bbb F_{13^4}$:

```
sage: EF.order().factor()
2^2 * 3^4 * 7
```

And the three-torsion points of order $3$ over $F$ are:

```
sage: for P in EF.points():
....:     if P.order() == 3:
....:         print P
....:         
(9 : 6 : 1)
(9 : 7 : 1)
(a : 2*a + 5 : 1)
(a : 11*a + 8 : 1)
(4*a^2 + 3*a : 5*a^2 + 7*a + 8 : 1)
(4*a^2 + 3*a : 8*a^2 + 6*a + 5 : 1)
(9*a^2 + 9*a + 4 : 5*a^2 + 5*a : 1)
(9*a^2 + 9*a + 4 : 8*a^2 + 8*a : 1)
sage:
```

As expected, there are two points with $a$ as the first coordinate.

---

The polynomial needed for the $9$-division has the following factors:

```
sage: for f, multiplicity in E.division_polynomial(9).factor():
....:     print f
....:     
x + 1
x + 4
x + 11
x + 12
x^3 + 4*x^2 + 8*x + 7
x^3 + 8*x^2 + x + 6
x^3 + 9*x^2 + 9*x + 9
x^9 + 2*x^7 + 5*x^6 + 11*x^5 + x^4 + 12*x^3 + 11*x^2 + 7*x + 9
x^9 + 6*x^8 + 7*x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + 10*x^4 + 9*x^3 + 2*x^2 + 7*x + 7
x^9 + 10*x^8 + 6*x^7 + 7*x^6 + 3*x^5 + 3*x^4 + 7*x^3 + 9*x^2 + 7*x + 10
```

Again, the linear factors correspond to the points in $(x,y)\in E(\Bbb F_{13})$ with first component $x\in\{-4,-11,-12\}=\{11,2,1\}$.

To have all $9$-division points, we need a field containing the roots of all above factors. There is exactly one field $L$ with $\Bbb F_{13^9}$ elements *up to isomorphism*, which can be constructed from the polynomial ring $\Bbb F_{13}[b]$ by going modulo one of the above polynomials of degree nine, taken in `x` = $b$.

Of course, we can no longer compute all points in $E(L)$, then their order, then restrict to those of order exactly nine, but we can construct them starting from the roots of the division polynomial.

For instance, for the polynomial defining $b$ (as a root) of degree nine we have the nine conjugates, giving rise to $18$ points of order $9$ on $E(L)$, we show only nine of them, using only one choice for the square root, as provided by sage, the other one differs by sign:

```
sage: EL = E.base_extend(L)
sage: for bb in b.minpoly().roots(ring=L, multiplicities=False):
....:     ybb = sqrt( bb^3 + 3*bb + 8 )
....:     P = EL.point( (bb, ybb) )
....:     print "Order %s for point with components:\n%s\n%s\n" % (P.order(), P.xy()[0], P.xy()[1])
....:     
Order 9 for point with components:
b
11*b^8 + 7*b^7 + 5*b^6 + 2*b^4 + 10*b^3 + 7*b^2 + 6*b + 11

Order 9 for point with components:
3*b^8 + 4*b^7 + 4*b^6 + 3*b^5 + b^4 + 9*b^3 + 9*b
8*b^8 + 12*b^7 + 5*b^6 + 11*b^5 + 9*b^4 + 2*b^3 + 2*b^2 + 12*b + 12

Order 9 for point with components:
11*b^8 + 5*b^7 + 7*b^6 + 2*b^5 + 7*b^4 + 7*b^2 + b + 12
2*b^8 + 6*b^7 + 2*b^6 + 7*b^5 + 5*b^4 + 6*b^3 + 5*b^2 + 11

Order 9 for point with components:
4*b^8 + 9*b^7 + 4*b^5 + b^4 + 6*b^3 + b^2 + 11
b^8 + b^7 + 5*b^6 + b^5 + 12*b^4 + 2*b^2 + 5*b + 7

Order 9 for point with components:
6*b^8 + 10*b^7 + 3*b^6 + 8*b^5 + 2*b^4 + 10*b^3 + 3*b + 11
10*b^8 + 5*b^7 + 3*b^6 + 3*b^5 + 3*b^4 + 7*b^3 + b^2 + 7*b + 11

Order 9 for point with components:
5*b^8 + 6*b^7 + b^6 + 6*b^5 + 8*b^4 + 2*b^2 + 9*b + 10
7*b^8 + 3*b^7 + 6*b^6 + b^5 + 11*b^4 + 9*b^3 + 2*b^2 + 5*b + 4

Order 9 for point with components:
8*b^8 + 10*b^7 + 5*b^5 + 6*b^3 + 12*b^2 + b + 9
2*b^7 + 2*b^6 + 3*b^5 + 5*b^4 + 12*b^3 + 10*b^2 + 6*b + 5

Order 9 for point with components:
6*b^8 + b^7 + 7*b^6 + 3*b^5 + 6*b^4 + 2*b^3 + 10*b + 6
11*b^8 + 9*b^7 + 4*b^6 + 4*b^5 + 12*b^4 + 5*b + 10

Order 9 for point with components:
9*b^8 + 7*b^7 + 4*b^6 + 8*b^5 + b^4 + 6*b^3 + 4*b^2 + 5*b + 6
2*b^8 + 5*b^7 + b^6 + 5*b^5 + 7*b^4 + 6*b^3 + 4*b + 5

sage:
```